# Экспорт из Access в Excel

Tags: excel, vba, access, visual-basic

Как можно из таблицы Access перенести на отдельный лист в Excel через VBA?

Comment: `DoCMD.TransferSpreadsheet`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, откуда и что вы собираетесь переносить. 
1. в каком именно приложении вы пишите макрос? Вы из Access экспортируете данные или из Excel импортируете?
2. Вам нужно перенести всю таблицу, или по какой-то выборке? Если выборка, то придется использовать SQL - как у вас с этим языком запросов?